# Emacs as Finder/Explorer -- copy files

Tags: emacs, dired

I often want to copy files from one half (C-x 2) to the other of emacs, with different dired buffers in both halves.

The obvious way is to mark the files in one window, go to the other, move to the directory name, mark beginning, go to end, copy to the ring, return to the first half, and finally initiate the copy while pasting the name of the buffer from the ring.

Is there a shorter way to copy from one dired buffer to the other?

**edit**

Thanks, BRPocock. Under dired-dwim customization, I only see:

[image: dired-dwim customization]

Comment: Yes, if you're unfamiliar with Customize: You adjust the setting (here with the “Toggle” button, and then choose to apply it with the “Set for Current Session” or “Save for Future Session” menu items. You can also, as you pointed out below, manually edit the elisp in .emacs, but the Customize interface is generally more user-friendly, if you're not comfortable with Lisp programming.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Under `Customize Group: Dired` you can use the `Dired Dwim Target` option to default to copying to the other dired window. (`customize-apropos <Ret> dwim <Ret>` should find it, as well)

Comment: Answer is a bit cryptic, but helpful nevertheless. To do what I describe in the question, it is enough to add (setq dired-dwim-target t) to one's .emacs. Calling dired-do-copy ('C') will then suggest the other directory displayed.

Comment: I figured the Customize interface was safer than directing someone into the land of elisp … no offense, never know who should be "kept out" of their own .emacs, lest havoc ensue. Glad to be of service.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry, I don't understand what's so onerous about copying the directory name and yanking it when prompted for the target directory. And if you do this "often", as you say, then the same directory should be in your history list, accessible using <kbd>M-p</kbd> etc. -- you should only need to select and copy it once.

Another approach to reusing something like the directory name is to use the *secondary selection*.  That persists when you change the region etc.  I bind yanking it to <kbd>C-M-y</kbd>. See http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SecondarySelection.

Comment: The number of keystrokes is excessive. I use emacs dired instead of Finder, and the target directory changes so using the secondary selection is not suitable. I am looking for copy-to-other-dired-buffer command. Does one exist?